# Fastest way to deserialize objects from Azure Blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, ravendb, azure-blob-storage

After experiencing a ton of outages with our central RavenDb, we're looking to cache certain objects in Azure Blob Storage.  Redis does not have the same SLA guarantees as ABS, so Redis has been ruled out

Retrieval and deserialization of these objects happens every minute and needs to happen extremely quickly.

Here is a code that we're trying to use to deserialize, however it is about 5-6x slower than retrieving objects from Raven.  Anyway to optimize it? Object size is about 8mb

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(entityId + ".json");

var serializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var accountOut =  serializer.Deserialize<Account>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you identify what is 5-6x slower? Is it the deserialization stuff? If so, how were you deserializing with Raven? (I don't know what it is) Or is it `GetBlockBlobReference`? If so, I am afraid there is nothing you can do with ABS. May be switching for an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: The fastest way should be to store and read binary data with the BinaryFormatter or you do it by yourself.

Comment: @fharreau I do not know what is causing the 5-6x difference, but am assuming that it is about serialization.  However, RavenDb is storing its objects as JSON internally. GetBlockBlobReference does not call Azure, simply creates an in-memory object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that using a single serializer object, without re-creating in every cycle of the loop was the fix for the issue.  Once, we started caching JsonSerializer object and re-using it, the performance of deserialization from Blob Storage became 50% of that from RavenDb

Comment: A thought - with serialization, one should also consider memory costs, very frequent serialization causes much more GC cycles

Comment: thanks a lot for including this answer, very important for us to know

Answer (score 0):

Want speed and can't use Redis (for whatever reason)? There's only one right answer: [**CosmosDB**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction).

It's very fast and it's backed by SSD storage.
99.99% availability within a single region (just click through the Portal UI to achieve geo-replication if you need that).

Comment: I was under the impression that CosmosDb has a limit of 2mb per object?

Comment: Yes, you're right - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources#documents Maybe you can semantically split those JSONs? Silly proposal, i know. Why did you drop Redis? The Premium tier has master/slave nodes and persistence (RDB).